# Install specific version of Bonsai Elasticsearch in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, heroku, bonsai-elasticsearch

Is it possible to install a specific version of Bonsai Elasticsearch in Heroku ? 
I'm trying to follow the documentation with this command line => `heroku addons:create bonsai:[plan] [-a APP_NAME] [--version=X.Y]` with this link https://docs.bonsai.io/article/194-heroku

I want to install 6.5.4 version. The command always install me latest version of ES which is 7.2.0

Anyone has same issue ? How can I fix this ?

Thx by advance !

---

Answer (score 2):

You are going on right path.

You can do

```
heroku addons:create bonsai --version=6.5.4
```

for installing 6.5.4 version as per this documentation. Reference: https://docs.bonsai.io/article/194-heroku

What error you are facing after running this command?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. But when I launch the command with `--version=6.5.4` is not taking into account. 7.2.0 version is always install..

No error is report

Comment: Bonsai only supports the latest version of Elasticsearch when using it's free (sandbox) tier. If you want to set a specific (older) version, you will have to move to a paid tier.